# header blanco cuando se levanta servidor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo una pagina web, con js agregue la funcionalidad de que el background del header es transparente, y cuando el usuario hace scroll se pone un background negro. Ahora el problema viene cuando se hace la primer recarga de pagina TODO el header es blanco y luego cuando se scrollea cambia a negro y luego a transparente, es decir que funciona bien, pero el primer despliegue SIEMPRE se ve blanco primero, cuando recargo la pagina no sucede solo suicede la primera vez. Aca les dejo el codigo y un editor para que lo vean
https://1567062.playcode.io

```
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/logoo" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
        <button id="abrir"><i class="bi bi-list"></i></button>
        <nav id="nav">
            <button id="cerrar"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></button>
        <ul class="contenedor-items">
            <li class="items"><a href="#">- Nosotros</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#">- Clientes</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#">- Servicios</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#">- Pedi tu cotización</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="section-1">
    <main>
        <div class="carrousel">
            <img src="https://fondosmil.com/fondo/29366.jpg" alt="" id="carrouselImg" draggable="false">                
        </div>
        </section>
        <div class="asd"></div>
    </main>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.no-scroll{
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .5s;

}


nav{
    display: flex;
}

.contenedor-items{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 4em;
}

#abrir{
    align-self: center;
    display: none;
}

a{
    font-size: 1.35rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.items{
    list-style: none;
    transition: .5s;
    position: relative;
}

.items::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.1px;
    background-color: #F2A71B;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

li:hover{
    transform: scale(1.37);
}

li:hover::after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

#section-1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carrousel{
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.carrousel img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.asd{
    height: 500px;
}

#cerrar{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 805px){
    /* #abrir{
        display: block;
    } */

    #cerrar,#abrir{
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 3rem;
        background-color: transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
    }

    nav{
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
        padding: 2rem;
        align-items: end;
        gap: 2em;
    }

    .nav-visible{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .contenedor-items{
        flex-direction: column;

        
    }

    #header{
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}
```

```
    "https://fondosmil.com/fondo/29366.jpg",
    "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/9c/6b/fe9c6be5759c12298688b2dd97cd5fd1.jpg",
    "https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/769/76/924/1920x1080-green-mountain-nature-1920x1080-wallpaper-preview.jpg" 
]

const header = document.querySelector("#header");
const carrouselImg = document.querySelector("#carrouselImg");
let currentIndex = 0;


function showImg(index) {
    // Hacemos el array circular para que siempre este dentro
    carrouselImg.src = imgURLS[(index % imgURLS.length + imgURLS.length)%imgURLS.length];
}

function nextImg() {
    currentIndex = currentIndex+1;
    showImg(currentIndex);
}

setInterval(nextImg, 3000);

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 53) {
        header.style.position = "fixed";
        header.style.background = "black";
    } else {
        header.style.background = "transparent";
    }
});

const nav = document.getElementById("nav")
const abrir = document.getElementById("abrir")
const cerrar = document.getElementById("cerrar")

abrir.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    nav.classList.add("nav-visible")
    document.body.classList.add("no-scroll")
})

cerrar.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    nav.classList.remove("nav-visible")
    document.body.classList.remove("no-scroll")
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como decís, tu código funciona bien. El tema es que tu header, al no definirle una position utiliza static por default, por eso es que en la primera recarga se ve el color blanco, también por defecto, y aún teniendo la transparencia, los demás elementos siguen allí (podes cambiarle el color a tus anchor tags para verlo). En fin, creo que asignándole desde el principio una position: fixed, tu objetivo se cumple. (Ah, y en el caso de que no quieras que sea visible en absoluto antes de hacer scroll simplemente podes empezar con un display: none y cambiárselo a display: flex al hacer scroll) Saludos y muy buena la foto de your name.